# UML MVC pattern List class use

Tags: model-view-controller, uml, class-diagram

When designing a class diagram for a theoretical MVC-Pattern-based system, is it best to use List classes?

For example:

**With List class:**

[image: diag 1]

**Without list class:**

[image: diag 2]

I personally feel the latter is a better approach due to less code duplication, is there a better approach to this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think there is a need for a list class. Your controller can hold all references to the model.

Regardless of that, your UML models have a problem: in both cases you have an attribute `customers:Customer[]` and an composition link. This means that you have TWO references from the controller (or list) to the model. Either remove the attribute or the link.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you to use swimlanes, one lane per structure component (MODEL / VIEW / CONTROLLER) and a separate lane for the database

a sample example would look like this

[image]